# Restore messages function to the default ones

Tags: warning-messages, options, usage-messages, default

Times ago I used the command Off[NDSolve::tag].
Now I've been forgetting which message I removed and I would like to restore it.
Someone knows if is there a way to reset all the default messages ?

Comment: Does `On[NDSolve]` work for you?

Comment: @Somos I've just tried and on my version 12.1 and it doesn't work. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: AFTER evaluation of NDSolve command try to evaluate Messages[NDSolve]. It will list all   messages that occured during evaluation. Not printed messages will be wrapped by  $Off[ ].

Comment: Much thanks this is what I need

Comment: @user18792 Post it as an answer?

Comment: Please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!  You can also upvote it now that you have sufficient reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFTER evaluation of NDSolve[ ] command evaluate Messages[NDSolve]. It will list all messages that occurred during evaluation. Suppressed messages are wrapped by head $Off.

Comment: And `On @@@ Keys@Messages@NDSolve` will turn them all on, if desired.  (It turns on the ones that are already on, too, but it's faster than figuring out how to turn on only the ones that are off.)